# saving a flash movie with just the stage

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, flash-cs5

how to I save/export a flash movie so that it just saves the contents inside of the stage?
There are certain things that overlap the stage and fade into it from the ouside in which I don't want to be able to be seen when increasing the screen size of the movie.

basically, I want to be able to make the screen as big as I want (using percentage in browser, and yes everythings a vector) with nothing but the stage showing.

How would I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on how complex your movie is you could create a mask layer as our uppermost layer which contains a rectangle matching the size of the stage. Apply the mask to all the layers below.

Comment: not complex at all.
but I'm sorry, im sort of new to flash.  How would I make the mask?

Comment: Create a new layer and right-click on it. Select `Mask` from the pop up menu. The mask layer will support a single shape, movie clip or text field. By default the layer immediately below will be masked. Masked items are only visible through the masking shape or movie clip. By dragging other into position between the indented masked layer and the mask layer itself you can apply the mask to multiple layers.

Comment: so if just the one immediately below the mask layer is masked, how do I get all of the other layers masked under that mask as well?
If thats what I need to do?

Comment: I applied the mask to all of my layers, but for some reason it wont mask all of the layers that I have?  Specifically the ones that are in folders to keep the layers organized.

Comment: You can't mask a folder. It's a bit of a hack but you could duplicate your mask to to the uppermost layer in a folder than apply it as a mask to the folder's layers.